# IF ISBLANK FORMULA

Tags: if, isblank

I'm trying to get a validation rule to check a Date Field called Triage_Stop_Time and if there is a value in the field it will make my Billing Picklist required with an error message "Required". If there is no value in the Triage_Stop_Time field then it will make the Billing Picklist blank or put None as a value. I am using Salesforce Classic and stuck with this. It will run the check and say the Billing is required but then when I fill in a value in the Picklist it just keeps looping saying it is "Required" even after I fill a value in? I'm missing something here can someone help?

IF(ISBLANK(Triage_Stop_Time__c), false, true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do both things with a validation rule. Validation rules cannot write values to fields. For that, you'd need something like a workflow rule with a field update or use process builder.

That aside, it's best to think of validation rules as things that tell you when data is invalid (which for me at least is the opposite of how I'd usually think).

Your criteria here are simple, and you've basically laid it out in plain language already. Your data is invalid when:

- `Triage_Stop_Time__c` is not blank
- and `Billing__c` is blank

Translating that to a validation formula is then straightforward.

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Triage_Stop_Time__c)),
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Billing__c))
)
```

I hope it's clear how the formula follows from the "plain language" description.

If you choose to do the second part using a workflow rule, it's a similar process. The big difference is that with a workflow rule, you're using the formula to determine when the workflow actions *should* be run (so, basically the opposite of how the validation rule formula behaves).

Comment: Hey Derek, Thank you for that it helps, I didn't know validation rules couldn't write data but now I do! So the validation formula you suggested provides an error message saying "Error: Field Billing__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions." So I'm assuming I would have to change the field type?

Comment: @ETM d'oh, I forgot about how picklists need special treatment. Updated my answer. Another way to check if a picklist field is blank would be `ISPICKVAL(Billing__c, '')`

Comment: Thank you again!!

Comment: @ETM The StackExchange culture encourages marking answers as accepted if it solved your issue (or the most helpful/correct one to you if you get multiple answers). Doing this is optional, but it is a nice and helpful gesture for several reasons. It gives both you and the person who wrote the answer reputation points, but perhaps more importantly it signals to the community that your question has been answered and helps other people with similar questions (from google and the official Salesforce developer forum, mostly) easily identify solutions that are likely to work.

Comment: Done and thank you.